# Calculating work from enthaply and internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, heat-engine

When do we use enthalpy to calculate work done and when do we use internal energy?

For e.x in ideal rankine cycle (working substance steam) the work done by the turbine(3-4) is calculated from the change in enthalpy h<sub>3</sub> - h<sub>4</sub> . Whereas, in the dual cycle(working substance air), the expansion work from 3a-4 is given by change in internal energy, even though the work done in both cases is adiabatic. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rankine cycle is a **continuous flow** operation, whereas the dual cycle is a sequence of **batch** operations.  In a continuous flow process, different parts of the working fluid are subjected to different parts of the process at the same time.  In a batch operation, all parts of the working fluid are subjected to different parts of the process at different times.  So, in a continuous flow operation, each piece of equipment is an *open system*, with working fluid continuously flowing in and out while, in a batch operation, each segment of the process is carried out in a *closed system*.  For an open system, the appropriate equation to use in analyzing the thermodynamic changes is the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics.  In a closed system, the appropriate equation is the closed system version of the first law of thermodynamics.  The open system version of the first law involves the change in enthalpy through the piece of equipment and the so-called  *shaft work* (which does not include the work to push fluid into and out of the piece of equipment); the closed system version of the first law involves the change in internal energy and the total work.  The open system version was derived directly from the closed system version, so it is entirely equivalent.  But, in practice, it is more convenient to use the open system version for flow processes.

Comment: Looks promising. I will look into your answer throughly. Thanks for the effort.